# How to calculate a change in velocity as a result of friction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

If you have an object moving at $u$ initial velocity with no acceleration, and a surface with a *$$\mu_k$$* frictional coefficient, how can you calculate its final velocity after having traveled $d$ distance over this surface?

Would I also need mass $m$ to figure this out?

I've tried looking for a formula to help me out but unfortunately I was unable to find it... I'd really appreciate some help on the matter!

Comment: You need mass *m* for , Frictional force $F_f =\mu_k mg$...

Comment: The mass cancels out because $a=F/m$

Comment: And do you need the final velocity? Your question is a bit confusing on that part

Comment: @YuzurihaInori Hi, sorry for that. I'm trying to calculate the final velocity once it's reached the d distance.

Comment: That's right too....With final velocity $v$ he gets $a$ , so why need $\mu_k$ ?

Comment: @NehalSamee We do need the $\mu_k$ for the decelaration.

Comment: Yeah...Confused due to earlier question before editing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frictional force is $\mu_k mg$ opposite to $u$. We get a decelaration of $a=\mu_k g$ and this finally gives us $v=\sqrt{u^2-2ad}$.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Equate work done by friction force per travel distance $d$ to the loss of kinetic energy :
$$ \mu_k mg\,d = \frac {m (u - v)^2}{2} $$
Then solve equation for $v$.